# How can I remove a newline from redirected output

Tags: io-redirection

Can I remove a newline if I redirect output like this?

```
echo "a" >> file
```

I have something similar in my script which contains a for loop that redirects every character (except numbers) to a file. 
But my goal is to have this output in one line. Let's say I redirect the "a" ten times so it should look like this:

```
a a a a a a a a a a
```

but it looks like this:

```
a
a
a
a 
[etc.]
```

Comment: Use `echo -n` or `printf`.

Comment: I should have looked at man echo in the first place. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @KKor don't rely on `man echo` - your shell may have a builtin `echo` command that behaves differently. See for example [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/65304)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're specifically asking about `echo`, you can use `-n` to suppress the newline:

```
$ echo -n "test" >> outputfile
```

If you're asking more generally how to suppress newlines in piped or redirected data, this is a cat with *many* skins.  One easy way is with `tr`:

```
$ do_stuff | tr -d "\n" >> outputfile
```

If you're just getting started with scripting and outputting data, it might be best to get out of the habit of using `echo` altogether in favor of `printf`:

```
$ printf "test" >> outputfile
```

`printf` is superior to `echo` in many ways and for many reasons, not least of which is that it *only* prints what you explicitly tell it to (and, arguably more importantly, in the format in which you want it).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'd want to delete the newlines, but replace them with spaces:

```
for ((i=0; i<10; ++i)); do
    echo a
done | tr '\n' ' ' >file
```

This simply post-processes your `echo` output and saves the data into `file` (truncating it first, if it already exists).

Or do something more fancy (in `bash`),

```
for ((i=0; i<10; ++i)); do
    array+=( "a" )
done

printf '%s\n' "${array[*]}" >file
```

This has the advantage of terminating the line properly with a final newline, while all the elements of the array are delimited by space (the first character of `$IFS`).

Or, with `/bin/sh`:

```
i=0
set --
while [ "$i" -lt 10 ]; do
    set -- "$@" "a"
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done

printf '%s\n' "$*" >file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `seq 1 10`; do
  printf "a " >> file
done
```

should do the trick.

Comment: or `for ...  do ... done >> file` to avoid reopening `file` multiple times